# Querying Alternative Solutions in Prolog.NET

Tags: c#, prolog

I am a university student, who's quite new to Prolog. I am currently developing a C# Application which should be integrated with Prolog using any suitable prolog-C# library. I have found [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.hodroj.net/) (Developed by Ali Hodroj) to be a pretty good solution for my scenario and it suits my requirements as well. However, I am having a little trouble when querying alternative solutions for a particular predicate when using it. For instance, a predicate like,

```
add(X,Y,Ans) :- Ans is X+Y.
```

will have only one particular answer, which would be 3 if the user entered 1 and 2 for X and Y respectively. But,

```
female(maria). 
female(emma). 
parent(bobby, emma).
parent(bobby, maria). 
daughter(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y), female(Y).
```

if the daughter(X,Y) predicate is queried as daughter(bobby,D), the D will have two values which are emma and maria, which can be iterated by pressing ";" in a Prolog environment. But when using C# with Prolog.NET, I can only get one particular value. For example:

```
AbstractTerm a = new AbstractTerm();
PrologClass proClass = new PrologClass();
proClass.daughter("bobby", a);
```

When invoking the above daughter(X,Y) method from the C# environment, it will only return me one particular solution (emma), what I require is to get the other solution which is maria as well. I have tried many things but I cannot seem to get the other value/s no matter what. I would really appreciate if someone can tell how this can be achieved! It would be a great assist for my project work!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you try C# interface for SWI-Prolog written by Uwe Lesta : http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html ?

Comment: I've actually been curious myself about embedding prolog; have you tried that linked-to implementation? Any pros/cons/opinions?

Comment: @joel76: Well I didn't try it as it didn't have a proper documentation or a sample to get started with. If you can provide me any code snippets how I can use it, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: The example showns there http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx works with Visual Studio 2010 and Seven 32 bits (there were few problems with 64 bits, may be they are fixed). Be sure to have the latest versions of SWI-Prolog and C# interface : SwiPlCs_1.1.60301.0.zip

Comment: I think that writing a reflexive interface in .NET could take less than adapting a 'proprietary' solution (both are binary available only), especially if that does not handle your use case. Do you know about Meta programming in C# ?

Comment: I think that SWI-Prolog is launched in a thread of the main process. With this interface, you can do everything you do with the SWI-Prolog console, for example you can consult file 'xxx.pl' with PlQuery.PlCall("consult('my_file.pl')") and work with it using PlCall.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually not true, as this implemetation does not have `bagof`**

Wrap the queries in `bagof/3`, like this:

```
bagof( (X,Y), daughter(X,Y), Result).
```

You should receive a list of all results. Look at the other predicates for finding all solutions to a goal for more options.

Comment: thanks for your input mate. But you're suggesting me to query from the Prolog environment. However, what I require is to get this done using C#, with the help of the Prolog.NET. Perhaps I should change my question for it to be more clear I guess. Thank you anyways. :)

Comment: Well..it's kind of problematic, as prolog.NET doesn't support all the built-in predicates of Prolog. As far as I'm aware, I can only use the predicates that I have defined in my prolog file when using prolog.NET (except quite a few basic built-in Prolog predicates). I found out that I can use the findall/3 predicate to find all the results as well. But in that case, as u suggested, I would have to define them in my Prolog file. But my requirement is to get this done using the prolog.NET itself.

Comment: @PrabashDarshana I actually took a look at the page you linked to. It looks to me like this is a _very_ incomplete Prolog implementation, I would say barely useful. You might want to look into extending it if you actually want to use it for anything, and I would be surprised if you manage to find support from anyone but the guy who actually wrote it.